# SharePoint Custom Action on document set in docsethomepage.aspx

Tags: workflow, document-set, custom-actions

I would like to create a custom action inside Manage ribbon group that would start a workflow on a document set not a file within.

I have spent some time trying to enable the custom action created in  [SharePoint Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjSuN.png)
until I have found out that I need to select a document inside and action would execute on chosen document, not on document set itself as I have expected. I know I can add a function to a menu in a list of document sets (folders), but, for some reason, I would prefer to have it available in a menu in a document set home form, like Edit, Delete, Capture Version etc.